# Beaglebone black: cannot initiate connection to debian

Tags: mysql, networking, debian

I realize this could be more of a hardware issue but thought I'd ask. 
Working on a database project and utilizing a beaglebone black. I've checked the network connection and gateway IP information, and it all seems good. When I try to run the command to install the MySQL server/client:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

the connection seems to time out, and I get

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main libaio1 armhf 0.3.109-3 Cannot initiate the connection to ftp.us.debian.org:80 (2610:148:1f10:3::89). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::89 80]
```

(a long list of these similar errors as different fetches are attempted).
I've also tried some npm options to no avail. I am trying to figure out if this is a DSN issue, something with the speed of my connection, or if there is some server IP edit I am missing in the network interfaces file. Any advice or info from experienced beaglebone users appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself - can be fixed by opening /etc/apt/sources.list

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then changing the 'http' to 'ftp' for debian-src as follows:

```
deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

etc.